# Using Spring, Basic Auth and LDAP, how can I get the supplied username?

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap, jersey, basic-authentication

I'm authenticating users against LDAP with spring security. My bean config looks like this

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" > 
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:http-basic/>  
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>          
    <security:ldap-authentication-provider user-dn-pattern="cn={0},ou=users"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:ldap-server url="${ldap.url}/${ldap.base}" />
```

This works great, but now I want access to that {0} username in code. I do have Jersey managing the service interface and I found some tutorials on creating a filter and digging through the request. However, I was hoping there would be an easier way to get at it, seeing as how Spring has already done all the work and has the username in plain text and ready to be shipped off to the LDAP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) auth = [SecurityContextHolder.getContext()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.8.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html#getContext%28%29).getAuthentication();

auth.getName();

Comment: Wunderbar. Thank you fine sir, it's exactly what I was looking for.